# Why won't apt-get update/upgrade install ALL outstanding security packages

Tags: upgrade, updates

When I login to my 14.04.4 LTS VPS I see the standard system info along with:

```
7 packages can be updated
7 updates are security updates
```

When I run apt-get update/upgrade these packages remain uninstalled.

How do I install these packages? Do I need to install these packages? What's the deal?

Thanks!

Comment: The MOTD is updated infrequently. When you run `sudo apt-get upgrade` are any packages held back?

Comment: post the command you ran and all the output.

Comment: Yes. The following packages have been kept back: linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic

Answer (score 1):

Solution to held back message is to directly do updates to listed packages held (all of them)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

... then afterword re-issue your original command

Comment: Do I need these updates if they are held back? That's only three packages but the MOTD lists 7? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: They are held to give you the chance to decide whether you want them or not.  Security updates should always get installed.